# SQL query date string by range

Tags: sql, postgresql

Spec: I need to query by date month and day only (ignoring year)

Input:

```
start := '2015-12-29'
end := '2016-01-03'
```

Output:

```
1986-12-30
1980-01-01
1982-12-31
1978-01-03
...
```

Current solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE RIGHT(birthday,5) >= $1
  AND RIGHT(birthday,5) <= $2
```

But this only works when the year not overlap, what's the easiest solution for this case?

My simplest solution is by generating the SQL string using another language:

```
if start_year == end_year {
    date_where = `
    AND RIGHT(birth_date,5) >= RIGHT(` + Z(start) + `,5)
    AND RIGHT(birth_date,5) <= RIGHT(` + Z(end) + `,5)
    `
} else {
    date_where = `
    AND ( RIGHT(birth_date,5) >= RIGHT(` + Z(start) + `,5)
        AND RIGHT(birth_date,5) <= '12-31'
    ) OR ( RIGHT(birth_date,5) >= '01-01'
        AND RIGHT(birth_date,5) <= RIGHT(` + Z(end) + `,5)
    )`
}
```

I believe there are better way than this..

Answer (score 1):

A date is not a string, don't use string functions to handle a date. Use date functions like [EXTRACT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

```
SELECT  '2015-12-29'::date,
    EXTRACT(month from '2015-12-29'::date),
    EXTRACT(day from '2015-12-29'::date);
```

Comment: btw I'm using `JSONB`, so it's a `TEXT`/string, not a `DATE`, I just simplify the question so it doesn't look like a `JSONB`..

Comment: When you know it is a date, cast it to a date and handle it like a date.